# Application is not launching when i click on default firebase notification, Android 6.0.1

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have found that on **Android 6.0.1** when our app is in background and notification comes form firebase and if i tap on notification, our application is not launching.... only whenever my application is on foreground, i can get onMessageReceived and i am handing with below code.
Whenever user click on notification **SplashActivity** will be called

```
 @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Log.e("dataChat",remoteMessage.getData().toString());
        try
        {
            Map<String, String> params = remoteMessage.getData();
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(params);
            String strHref = jsonObject.optString(Constants.MyFirebase.HREF);
            if(strHref!=null && !strHref.equals("")){
                createNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), strHref);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void createNotification(String title, String href){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.MyFirebase.HREF, href);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "MyApp")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_icon)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText("")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true).build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("Channleld",
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }


        notificationManager.notify(0,  notification);  
}
```

But if my application is killed, if notification comes and if i click on that, I want to get data from my SplashActivity like below

```
Intent sourceIntent = getIntent();
if (sourceIntent != null) {
            Bundle bundle = sourceIntent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                String strHref = bundle.getString(Constants.MyFirebase.HREF, "");
```

But when i click on **notification (default)** nothing happens my **application is not launching**

AndroidMenifest.xml is like below

```
  <activity
            android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: remove this tag android:launchMode="singleTop"

Comment: Thanks, let me check

Comment: I have removed, it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove this tag from activity tag

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

as you have already used

`intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);`
in pending intent for the notification

and also use this

```
 <activity
            android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"   
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

no need to use this as well

```
           <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: I have tested without DEFAULT intent filter, it was not working, that's why i have added

Comment: alright , have you also try using  PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT ?

Comment: But when our app is killed, onMessageReceived will not call right, so our Notification will not come from our code.

Comment: onMessageReceived will always be called whether app is running or killed , thats what broadcast reciever is used for

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177640/discussion-between-siddhpura-amit-and-quick-learner).